# Вылезает куча ошибок при попытке подключить библиотеку GDI+

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "core.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;

...

void Create(int n, HDC ConsoleDc){
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
   HDC                 hdc=ConsoleDc;

   // Initialize GDI+.
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
   Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
   Image image(L"img.jpg");
   graphics.DrawImage(&image, 60, 10);
};
```

[image]
Помогите!

Comment: Хм. Какой-то баг в хедерах. Попробуйте перенести `#include <gdiplus.h>` повыше. И ещё: утащите `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` в `stdafx.h` (кстати, где он у вас?)

Comment: @VlaD, я недавно начал изучать язык, поэтому пока не до всего успел добраться. Объясните, для чего нужен этот stdafx.h? В нете написано "для предкомпилированных загловков". А что это? 
UPD перемещение gdiplus не помогло

Comment: @ололо: Это длинная история. В принципе-то они не нужны, но для ускорения компиляции пригодятся. Такой специфический хак от разработчиков компилятора. А если удалить gdiplus, на какой строке вылетит?

Comment: @VlaD, если убрать гдиплюс то опять ошибки:24 шт. Вот одна: 'to_string' : is not a member of 'std'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказывается подключать нужно в  этом порядке:

```
#include "core.h" 
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```